# Finding Patterns In A Data Using Coordinates

Tags: pattern-recognition

I am trying to find a theoretical approach to find patterns using a data set plotted on a graph. Below is the sample image of how the data looks on a plot.

[image]

I am wondering if there is an intuitive way by using coordinates to find if the set of points depict any specific patters like `curve` or `circle` or `line'?

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What do you want to know about these data?  What do the variables represent?  What kind of relationship do you think they might have?  You could throw your data thoughtlessly into many different clustering or regression algorithms.  But that doesn't mean the results will be meaningful.

Comment: @DanHicks - Yes, I agree. I am trying to solve the [problem presented](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07408170600733236) here, but differently.

Comment: In that case, you should rewrite your question in terms of that problem.  Explain the context and the problem, and what you think a different solution should look like.